# replace statement lambda with regular expression Lambda java 8 stream map

Tags: lambda, java-8

I have this map function as part of my stream. `parse.apply` is basically doing `Double::valueOf`. My intelliJ suggest me I can replace statement lambda with regular expression Lambda.

```
.map(x -> { return StringUtils.isEmpty(x) ? parse.apply("0") : parse.apply(x);
   })
```

If I didn't not have to worry about empty strings I could have done:
`.map(parse::apply)`. How do I do in this case?

Comment: What's the "regular expression Lambda"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter out all empty strings before reaching `.map`:

```
.filter(s -> !StringUtils.isEmpty(s))
.map(parse)
```

EDIT: if you want to replace empty strings with "0", then simply split one `map` into two separate operations. It won't affect efficiency and will make your code much easier to understand from functional programming point of view:

```
.map(s -> StringUtils.isEmpty(s) ? "0": s)
.map(parse)
```

EDIT2: when you call `Double::valueOf` you have to be aware that it can throw `java.lang.NumberFormatException` if given string has no double representation. Be aware of it.

Comment: But I want to replace the empty ones with 0